# converting boost::gregorian::date_duration to double

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

Is there a way to convert the boost::date_duration to a double.
I have the following code:

```
date be; 
date bd;
days t = (be - bd);
std::cout << "days are:" << t << std::endl;
```

This works fine and returns the no. of days. But I want to get the value in years, so if I divide t by 365, it only shows 0. `setprecision()` did not help either.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably caught by the fact that `boost::gregorian::days` overloads `operator/`. Convert to an integer first using `days()` and then divide by a floating-point value to get floating-point division.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::gregorian::date be(2000, 1, 1), bd(1950, 1, 1);
    boost::gregorian::days t = be - bd;
    std::cout << "days are: " << t << '\n'
              << "days/365 = " << t.days()/365.0 << '\n';
}
```

Note the output: your result is not equal to the number of years because a year is not 365.00 days.